# Changing layout programmatically

Tags: templates, theme-options

I have a theme that offers 2 choices of layouts within its options, stretched and boxed layout.

I wanted to try and make the front page keep the stretched layout look, while the rest of the site would use the boxed look.

I added this to the theme functions to try and accomplish this:

```
function yit_update_option( $id, $new_value, $hard_save = false ) {
YIT_Registry::get_instance()->options->update_option( $id, $new_value, $hard_save );
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'layoutchange');

function layoutchange(){
if( is_front_page() ) { 
        yit_update_option('general-layout-type', 'streched');
     }  
else {  
        yit_update_option('general-layout-type', 'boxed');
     }
}
```

The code checks if the user is on the front page or not, and adjust the layout options accordingly.

While this code does work, the **yit_update_option** updates the database options for the layout directly. If one person is on the front page and another person is on an interior page, this code will have problems keeping up. Would anyone else have suggestions on a better way to implement this solution?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: We'd need to know how is composed a "stretched" or a "boxed" layout and have the source code of your theme in order to help you further. Otherwise, you could search in the templates where is called `get_option( 'general-layout-type' )` and see what the theme does based on this option... Then reproduce this behavior with the same conditions you posted in your question...

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. There is a demo of the theme here:http://live.yithemes.com/desire/. Your idea is actually where I went first. For some reason, I could not easily discern what css changes were made so I thought coding a solution may be easier in this case.